# How to upload file through the api

Tags: python, api, rest, upload, robotframework

I am trying to automate the action of uploading a csv document to a file storage website.

I am attempting to do this test as a backend API test.

I have the file stored in my directory, and i want to send it as a parameter along with a json endpoint.

I am currently using python functions and doing the main test in robot framework.

Can anyone help me out?

```
def uploadFileContent(self,filename):
    path = self.makeurl("XXX.json")
    name = self.uploads_path+filename
    sys.stderr.write('\n> Filename: ' + name + '\n')    

    files = {filename: open(name, 'rb'), "name": "bulk_users_csv"}
    response = requests.post(path, files = files, cookies=self.cookies)
    print response.text
    self.status_code_should_be(201)
    return response
```

Comment: What website do you want to upload to? Could you give an example of what you mean with "send it as a parameter along with a json endpoint"?

Comment: Elaborate your requirement .. trying explaining main points .. and moreover making a api call from javascript you need `jsonp` not `json`

Comment: I am using the function above however the file is not being recognized as the correct format

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for the requests library, it looks like you're sending the wrong format for the request. This would explain the "not being recognized as the correct format" error you mention in the comments of your question.

The documentation for posting a [multipart-encoded file](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) shows an example like these:

```
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'), 'application/vnd.ms-excel', {'Expires': '0'})}
files = {'file': ('report.csv', 'some,data,to,send\nanother,row,to,send\n')}
```

You're using a "filename" key and a "name" key, neither of which seem to be supported.

You *can* [send arbitrary key/value pairs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), but if that's what you're trying to do, you can't send an open file handle as the data.